# Strategy for Handling History Time series Data in Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-kafka, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0

I'am working on insane Time Series Data. So, I have two Kafka Topic - 
1) Real time Time-Series Data of moving vehicles every 5 seconds.
2) History Time-Series Data of 10% of vehicles in case vehicles travels in remote area so, data is send once it comes into network, it may be after few hours, days or week.

So, my cassandra Table is somewhat like this

```
CREATE TABLE locationinfo (
imei text,
date text,
entrydt timestamp,
gpsdt timestamp,
lastgpsdt timestamp,
latitude text,
longitude text,
odo int,
speed int,
PRIMARY KEY ((imei, date), gpsdt) 
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (gpsdt ASC)
```

& I'm using Spark Streaming to fetch data from Kafka and inserting into Cassandra, here clustering key is gpsdt. Whenever History data comes from Kafka, lot of shuffle happens in table as we know the architecture of Cassandra. Data is nothing but stored in sequential order on the partition defined & for history entries records comes from between the lines. So, What happens is after a certain period of time, spark streaming application gets hang. After lot of search I found that there might be some problem with my table strategy, So if I create a table schema like this -

```
CREATE TABLE locationinfo (
imei text,
date text,
entrydt timestamp,
gpsdt timestamp,
lastgpsdt timestamp,
latitude text,
longitude text,
odo int,
speed int,
PRIMARY KEY ((imei, date), entrydt)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (entrydt ASC)
```

Here order is defined as per insertion time so whenever history data will come it will always append in the last and there will be no overhead of shuffling. But, in this case I wont be able to make range queries on gpsdt. So, I would like to know what should be the best strategy to handle this scenario. My load from kafka is more than 2k/sec.

Comment: Have you looked at using Kafka Connect for your ingest to Cassandra? It's specifically built for doing this kind of thing

Comment: @RobinMoffatt - Thanks for the prompt reply but the query is like data is already inserted into cassandra of real time and after some time history data comes So, either I use Kafka Connect or Spark, This is anyway handled at the cassandra Level which will do shuffling to adjust history records. So, I would like to understand how Kafka Connect will be helpful in this case or I can explain in more detail with example if there is any lag in my explanation.

Comment: Because you said "What happens is after a certain period of time, spark streaming application gets hang" I suggested that a dedicated streaming ingest framework, like Kafka Connect, could be another route to explore. It's part of Apache Kafka, and designed to scale horizontally to keep up with required ingest rates.

Comment: Without more info from the Spark application (logs around the time it hangs, maybe), hard to help there... If you'd like to read up on Kafka Connect, you can check out https://www.datastax.com/2018/12/introducing-the-datastax-apache-kafka-connector  .. The main point is that the connector has a dedicated framework to scaling and fault-tolerance, and we cannot see your Spark code to know how you are handling these things

Comment: @cricket_007 - Kafka Connect is paid or free ? and can we use it with normal Apache Cassandra instead of DSE ?

Comment: Kafka Connect is Apache licensed, free, open-source framework, and **included** with Apache Kafka since around Kafka 0.10 (but do not run it on the brokers). You can find the startup scripts named `connect-distributed.sh` for example if you have one of those versions. There are Enterprise connectors (like a handful of those from Confluent), but the Datastax one is free and open-source.

Comment: @cricket_007 - Thank you so much for your help, will definitely try this.